# It is possible to embed a MapActivity into another Activity without using Fragments?

Tags: android, android-activity

It is possible to embed a MapActivity into another Activity without using Fragments???

How can i achieve it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, use the TabLayout & use an intent to set the content of the Tab.

If you want to hide the tabs on the top you can reduce their size by using the following code.

```
tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(0).getLayoutParams().height =35;
```

I hope it helps...

Comment: does not exist's another way?

Comment: What exactly are your requirements ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want, you can handle directly a [`MapView`](http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/reference/com/google/android/maps/MapView.html) in you `Activity`.

Comment: is not what i am searching for